# Automating firefox to get xml

Tags: xml, flash, firefox, firebug, screen-scraping

I wish to get some data from a flash site. Now it is not possible to get the data directly from html. Now I have noticed using firebug that a xml file is sent to the browser containing the data I want, when I click on certain parts of the flash site. Is there any way to automate this?

Comment: Why don't you call the URL used by flash to retrieve this XML such as it shows in Firebug?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [flash.external.ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html). It's a way to communicate with JS.